# How to combine 2 bit columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am querying a database and I have 2 bit columns I need to combine (for this example if one is true the column must be true).

Something like: `Select col1 || col2 from myTable`

What is the easiest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
select col1 | col2 from myTable
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx

Comment: Hehe nice.  Though I try to avoid the bitwise operators. The | work as expected, but the & can be confusing, for example "select 1 & 2" returns "0".

Comment: @Andomar select 1 & 2 should return 0 so it is expected behavior

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming col1 and col2 are bit values, the closest Sql Server has to booleans.

To return 1 or 0:

```
select case when col1=1 or col2=1 then 1 else 0 end
from yourtable
```

To return true or false:

```
select case when col1=1 or col2=1 then 'true' else 'false' end
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use Bitwsise operations

& - All conditions needs to match

| - Any condition needs to match

```
    Select 
    -- Both need to Match
    1 & 0,   -- false  
    1 & 1,   -- true
    -- Only one condition needs to match
    1 | 1,   -- true
    0 | 1,   -- true
    1 | 0,   -- true
    0 | 0   -- False
```